# Error on syntax for generating coverage data from multiple files using lcov in Windows

Tags: linux, perl, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I would like some help... I'm having trouble coming up with the syntax to generate coverage data from multiple files using lcov in Windows.

I have gcov, lcov and genhtml installed on cygwin (I'm running this under Windows).  All of those files are inside cygwin/bin directory.  The coverage data I flush through I believe are perl scripts created from [JsTestCoverage](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/CodeCoverage) and has the following format:

```
SF:C:/test/jquery.js
DA:22,1
DA:23,1
...
end_of_record
SF:C:/test/testFile.js
DA:3,1
DA:6,1
...
end_of_record
//rinse and repeat till no more files
```

Note I have NOT used genhtml on the coverage data yet.

I then tried something like:

```
perl genhtml /../home/administrator/coverage1.dat /../home/administrator/coverage2.dat
```

But got an error saying:

```
genhtml: Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at genhtml line 1506.
```

I'm not sure whether I've got the process wrong either, being not from linux background at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to combine data from multiple gcov runs on separate compilation units?
I guess I understood that gcov was compilation-unit oriented, but I hadn't considered the implications; do I have it right that if you want to get collected, unified test coverage data to display on many compilation units you have to do some shenanigans to combine that data?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: yes I'm trying to combine multiple test coverage reports into one single report. The reason I did this is because according to the creaters of JsTestDriver, the browser doesn't cope well with running a lot of tests for coverage in a single run. So I had the test file split into multiple files. I have to combine the test results back to a single file, else I'll have pointless coverage statistics. But then I got stuck on the syntax... moreover, being not from linux background makes me unaware of the process I should follow in achieving what I want.

Comment: I just re-read the gcov documentation.  It doesn't appear to have a problem combining coverage data from multiple compilation units; it writes cumulative counts per file to into .gcda files.  <dig, dig, ...> oh, you're using some tool JsTestDriver that generates data sort of compatible with lcov.  ... the coverage data format doesn't seem that complicated, I'd expect a pretty simple script would be capable of composing it.  Sorry I'm not more help here :-{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out to be that there were repeating results in the coverage data.  I took out the repeating data, and the error disappeared.

Thanks.